# How to create multiple follow-up intents which takes any input from the end-user?

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, chatbot, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, fallback

I have 5 'Main Category Intents' which have 'Follow-up Intents (Sub-Categories)'. I want to add an intent to each of these 'Sub-Categories' which can take any input from the end-user. For instance, the chatbot would ask the user for any comments.

Is there a way I could create a method for this in the inline editor of the Fulfillment section?

I do not want to use fallback intents.

**Update:**

(Dialogflow Messenger Integration)

Here is one Intent Flow:

Category A: is the main intent
Category B: is a follow-up intent
Category C: is a follow-up intent of Category B (It can be any type of follow-up intent. Now I am open to Follow-up Fallback intent too)

There will be an open-ended question in the 'text response' section of the Category B follow-up intent.

Open-Ended question: Can you please provide me a brief of your query?

Now, Category C follow-up intent should be triggered which has no training phrases. I should be able to capture any input from the end-user.

(If Category C follow-up intent is a fallback follow-up intent, then I cannot pass parameters. I also cannot capture anything into a parameter since there are no training phrases.)

What are the best solutions for this? Can I write a method in the inline editor to capture this? If Yes, then what should be my code?

**The Flow:**

Bot:Can you please provide me a brief of your query?

End-User: XYZ (The input can be anything)

Comment: I also want to pass parameters.

Comment: Have you tried agent.setFollowupEvent?

Comment: Can you update your question to include any Intents that you currently have and possibly a sample conversation to illustrate what you're trying to do? (And can you clarify why you don't want to use fallback intents?)

Comment: @Gray_Rhino No, I have not. I have updated the question. Would it help me to solve the problem?

Comment: @Prisoner I have updated the question as requested. Let me know if you need any more clarifications.